# Angular is failing to load my app module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Facing some problem in loading the application module, please help, if need anymore code please let me know. Thanks in advance.

index.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/
1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/
1.5.7/angular-route.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/app.js"></script>  
<script src="/app/trading/controllers/members-controller.js"></script>
<script src="/app/components/paginate/paginate-filter.js"></script>
<script src="/app/trading/services/trading-service.js"></script>
```

app.js

```
angular.module("nkApp", [
  'ngRoute',
  'ngResource',
  'nkApp.members',
  'nkApp.paginate-filter',
  'nkApp.tradingService'
]).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
      when("/", {
        templateUrl: "/app/trading/members/members-view.html",
        controller: "membersController"
      }).
      when("/trading-api/members/:id", {
        templateUrl: "app/trading/members/member.html",
        controller: "membersController"
      }).
      when("/trading-api/members/:username", {
        templateUrl: "app/trading/members/member.html",
        controller: "membersController"
      }).
      otherwise({redirectTo: "/"});
  }]);
```

Console Error after removing ngResource

```
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=nkApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.7%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DnkApp.members%26p1%3D%255B%2524injector%253Amodulerr%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.5.7%252F%2524injector%252Fmodulerr%253Fp0%253Dui.bootstrap%2526p1%253D%25255B%252524injector%25253Anomod%25255D%252520http%25253A%25252F%25252Ferrors.angularjs.org%25252F1.5.7%25252F%252524injector%25252Fnomod%25253Fp0%25253Dui.bootstrap%25250AO%25252F%25253C%252540https%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.5.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A6%25253A412%25250Ale%25252F%25253C%25252F%25253C%25252F%25253C%252540https%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.5.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A25%25253A72%25250Ab%252540https%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.5.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A24%25253A115%25250Ale%25252F%25253C%25252F%25253C%252540https%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.5.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A24%25253A358%25250Ag%25252F%25253C%252540https%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.5.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A39%25253A374%25250Ar%252540https%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.5.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A7%25253A353%25250Ag%252540https%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.5.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A39%25253A222%25250Ag%25252F%25253C%252540https%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.5.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A39%25253A391%25250Ar%252540https%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.5.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A7%25253A353%25250Ag%252540https%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.5.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A39%25253A222%25250Ag%25252F%25253C%252540https%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.5.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A39%25253A391%25250Ar%252540https%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.5.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A7%25253A353%25250Ag%252540https%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.5.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A39%25253A222%25250Adb%252540https%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.5.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A43%25253A246%25250ABc%25252Fc%252540https%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.5.7%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A20%25253A359%25250ABc%252540https%25253A%25252F%25252Fajax.googleapis.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangularjs%25252F1.5.7%25252F
```

Comment: what is the error in the console????

Comment: sorry still the same issue.

Comment: Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=nkApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.7%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngResource%26p1%3D%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.5.7%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DngResource%250AO%252F%253C%2540https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.5.7%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A412%250

Comment: It's claiming the script... as I said.

Comment: Now we are talking; the issue is an injector, but please paste the error in you question, no in the comment.. ;)

Comment: sorry i am beginner and not clear i did google it and getting mixed answers and tried adding ngResource and un-chaining the config but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to *inject* `ngResource` without the script.

Just add it in your **HTML**:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular-resource.js"></script>
```

Comment: ngResource is not in fact required and it was added as a workaround suggested someone on web and I forgot to remove it. so ignore that.

Comment: @Kash, your error speaks for itself, it's claiming because you're trying to *inject* `ngResource` without load the script. What do you want finally? **DOC:** https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource

Comment: it does not work even I remove ngResource, ngResource added as a work around and pasted in the code by mistake. Error is still the same even ngResource is removed.

Comment: So, you got a new error, because the error that you pasted (https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=ngResource&p1=undefined) in your comment was claiming about `ngResource`.

Comment: Now it's claiming about `ui-bootstrap`... Do you have the necessary scripts?

Comment: how do you read these errors as they are really difficult to read. I am not sure about ui-bootstrap script. but you fixed it mate. i removed that from depedencies in controller and it works, you are star. but how to read these errors please let me know. thanks

Comment: Pleasure to help :). To read them you have to keep clicking on the links that `angular` provides. Check it as answer, please (on the left side <==).